# PHP preg_match Matching Wrong String

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a regular expression:

```
/\/(register)(?:\/activate\/(.{16}))?(?:\/(student|teacher|org))?\/?$/
```

Correct Matching Strings:

```
/register
/register/student
/register/activate/1234567890123456/
```

Mismatch Problem:

```
/register/register/register/register/student/
```

The above still matches while using preg_match in PHP. Any alternatives?

I have also tried limiting 'register' to 1:

```
\/((?:register){1})(?:\/activate\/(.{16}))?(?:\/(student|teacher|org))?\/?$
```

No luck.

It does not match using Debuggex, however it matched using http://www.phpliveregex.com/

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/o5i9GT27E-icwInu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use a ^ at the beginning of your string to anchor it.

```
/^\/(register)(?:\/activate\/(.{16}))?(?:\/(student|teacher|org))?\/?$/
 * here
```

Without using anchor at beginning it is actually matching like below:

```
/register/register/register/register/student/
                           ^----------------^
```

Comment: Oh yes, thank you! I have this on all of my other expressions, I guess it got removed somehow after many edits.

Comment: Also, use another character, such as ~ or #, to delimit your pattern. That way you won't have to escape all the /'s in your pattern: `"~/(register)(?:/activate/(.{16}))?(?:/(student|teacher|org))?/?$~"`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you're only trying to match the end of the string by using `$`. This means the regex will match your expression, regardless of what comes before it.

Having an expression `/bob$/` will match everything that ends with bob, e.g. `big bob`. That's exactly what's happening here.

You'll need to force `preg_match` to match the entire string (i.e. both the beginning and the end) by prefixing it with `^`.

```
/^\/(register)(?:\/activate\/(.{16}))?(?:\/(student|teacher|org))?\/?$/
```